# Java input procedure

Tags: java, io

What is the procedure to take an integer input from the user with:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Comment: How can this be [tag:swing] (Swing), [tag:java-ee] (HTML) & [tag:java-me] (LWUIT?) at the same time?  Further, if using a method for taking input from a stream, what does it have to do with any of those tags?

Answer (score 6):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: @Weebroots but make sure you wrap this in a `try-catch` block. It won't compile otherwise.